# webi reports official stamp

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I'm trying to add a stamp on the report to differentiate between the official and adhoc reports.
I'm trying to read the document owner name and if that name is not admin then the stamp should go away.
how can I read the name of the "owner" in the report details. 
can I use documentOwner() 
![report details displaying the owner of the document
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with `DocumentOwner()`?

Comment: The documentowner() is working fine.we want to verify the BO environment(dev or prd). Is there a way to capture the environment details l

Comment: That's a very different question from the one you asked!  No, there's no direct way to identify the BO cluster from within the report.  You could create a universe object that contains this info, and change the object's definition for each environment.